# Alterando o valor do objeto sem querer

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, objetos

Link do projeto: https://github.com/ThomasCaio/RPG2

self.enemy.damage retorna : {'physical': 45, 'fire': 25}

self.defense retorna : {'physical': 50}

```
def receive_damage(self):
    damage = self.enemy.damage
    defense = self.defense
    full_damage = 0
    for dmg in damage:
        full_damage += damage[dmg]
    for dmg in damage:
        if defense.get(dmg):
            damage[dmg] -= defense[dmg]
            if damage[dmg] < 0:
                damage[dmg] = 0
    final_damage = 0
    for dmg in damage:
        final_damage += damage[dmg]
    print(f'{self.enemy} atacou {self} em {full_damage} de dano.')
    print(f'{self} bloqueou {full_damage-final_damage} de dano e recebeu {final_damage}.')
    self.health -= round(final_damage)
```

O primeiro dano do player está funcionando perfeitamente. Essa função(receive_damage) tem tanto no player quanto no monstro, porém, quando acontece um ataque:

```
damage[dmg] -= defense[dmg]
```

essa linha do código reduz o dano do monstro. Não estou conseguindo resolver isso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente ( digo provavelmente porque não entendo muito bem como o seu jogo funciona ) o problema está no fato de você ter usado `-=` ao invés de um operador de subtração `-`. O resultado disso é que você terá o dano dele mesmo reduzido pela defesa. Exemplo:

```
def ataca():
    global dano,defesa
    dano -=  defesa
    print("O monstro te deu %.2f de dano."%dano)

dano = 30
defesa = 1.5

for i in range(30):
    ataca()
```

O correto deveria ser:

```
def ataca():
    global dano_total,defesa
    dano_causado = dano_total
    dano_causado -=  defesa
    print("O monstro te deu %.2f de dano."%dano_causado)

dano_total = 30
defesa = 1.5

for i in range(30):
    ataca()
```

Como você viu no exemplo acima, para corrigir o problema basta criar uma variável auxiliar para sofrer alterações da rodada atual, sem alterar a variável original. Se por acaso você fez `damage = self.enemy.damage` querendo criar uma variável auxilar, infelizmente este código também está errado. Pelo o que eu vejo, o `self.enemy.damage` é um objeto. Se você passar uma variável contendo a referência de um objeto para uma outra variável, todas as alterações de uma variável irão se refletir na outra. Isso porque você não está passando o objeto em si, mas sim o endereço de memória.
Caso o `self.enemy.damage` seja um dicionário, utilize o método `copy` para receber a referência de um novo objeto com os elementos iguais. Exemplo:

```
damage = self.enemy.damage.copy()
```

Comment: Pois então, não deveria apenas reduzir o valor da variável dano ao invés de reduzir o dano do self.enemy.damage?

Comment: Não se você for usar um dano fixo. Exemplo: Vamos dizer que o inimigo tem um dano de 90, o que você pode fazer é criar uma variável auxiliar para sofrer todas as alterações como a redução dela pela defesa do jogador. Dessa forma, numa determinada rodada, o dano sofrido pode ser de 75 pois foi calculado ele mais a defesa do jogador, porém, o dano do monstro continua sendo 90. Se você alterar o dano diretamente do monstro, nas próximas rodadas, o dano do monstro irá ser menor como no exemplo que eu dei na resposta.

Comment: E essa variável auxiliar não é o que eu fiz em damage? Eu coloquei ela pra receber o dano do monstro e sofrer a redução mas mesmo assim altera o dano do monstro.

Comment: Se a sua "variável auxiliar" está na linha 3 da sua função, então está errado. Pelo que eu vejo, a variável "damage" é um dicionário ou algum tipo de objeto. Você deve se lembrar que quando você passa um objeto para uma variável, você não está passando o objeto e sim um endereço de memória. Ou seja, as alterações da variável "damage" estão acontecendo também no "self.enemy.damage". Para que isso não aconteça basta usar o método "copy" do dicionário ( caso seja um dicionário ) para retornar um objeto com os elementos idênticos porém diferente do original na memória.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou certinho.